# In Node.js, on the console object, what is the context function?

Tags: node.js

Looking at the `console` object in the Node.js repl, I see it has a `context` function:

```
> console
Console {
  log: [Function: bound consoleCall],
  debug: [Function: bound consoleCall],
  info: [Function: bound consoleCall],
  warn: [Function: bound consoleCall],
  error: [Function: bound consoleCall],
  dir: [Function: bound consoleCall],
  time: [Function: bound consoleCall],
  timeEnd: [Function: bound consoleCall],
  trace: [Function: bound consoleCall],
  assert: [Function: bound consoleCall],
  clear: [Function: bound consoleCall],
  count: [Function: bound consoleCall],
  countReset: [Function: bound countReset],
  group: [Function: bound consoleCall],
  groupCollapsed: [Function: bound consoleCall],
  groupEnd: [Function: bound consoleCall],
  Console: [Function: Console],
  dirxml: [Function: dirxml],
  table: [Function: table],
  markTimeline: [Function: markTimeline],
  profile: [Function: profile],
  profileEnd: [Function: profileEnd],
  timeline: [Function: timeline],
  timelineEnd: [Function: timelineEnd],
  timeStamp: [Function: timeStamp],
  context: [Function: context],
  [Symbol(counts)]: Map {} }
```

This function, when called, seems to return an object similar to `console` but missing a few things:

```
> console.context()
{ debug: [Function: debug],
  error: [Function: error],
  info: [Function: info],
  log: [Function: log],
  warn: [Function: warn],
  dir: [Function: dir],
  dirXml: [Function: dirXml],
  table: [Function: table],
  trace: [Function: trace],
  group: [Function: group],
  groupCollapsed: [Function: groupCollapsed],
  groupEnd: [Function: groupEnd],
  clear: [Function: clear],
  count: [Function: count],
  assert: [Function: assert],
  markTimeline: [Function: markTimeline],
  profile: [Function: profile],
  profileEnd: [Function: profileEnd],
  timeline: [Function: timeline],
  timelineEnd: [Function: timelineEnd],
  time: [Function: time],
  timeEnd: [Function: timeEnd],
  timeStamp: [Function: timeStamp] }

> console.context() === console
false
```

Although it looks similar, it does not have the same functionality:

```
> console.context().log('hello world')
undefined
```

These items are in `console` but not in `console.context()`:

```
Console: [Function: Console],
[Symbol(counts)]: Map {}
context: [Function: context],
countReset: [Function: bound countReset],
```

The constructor `Console` and `countReset` are documented at
https://nodejs.org/api/console.html

The `[Symbol(counts)]` object might have something to do with the
implementation of `count` and `countReset`.

But `context` seems like it should be documented, and is not. What is
it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`console.context` is [experimental Chrome/V8 feature](https://umaar.com/dev-tips/153-log-management/) that creates a new context for console output. It doesn't have [Node-specific implementation](https://github.com/nodejs/node/commit/fb7a77524246feada872674b34bef80f4f7e649e), so it is supposedly implemented in V8.

Since it's experimental, there may be inconsistencies. `console.context` didn't work as expected for me in any recent Chromium versions, and it isn't supposed to provide useful results in Node.js.